# Problems with subclasses, unexpected arguments and unsolved references

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclass, superclass

So I'm trying to make an endless text adventure game (using help from [this](http://letstalkdata.com/2014/08/how-to-write-a-text-adventure-in-python-part-1-items-and-enemies/) site), but I'm having some problems with my classes:

```
class Item:
def __init__(self, name, desc, usable, value):
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc
    self.usable = usable
    self.value = value

def __str__(self):

    return "{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\n".format(self.name, self.desc, self.usable, self.value)


class Weapon(Item):

    def __init__(self, damage):
        self.damage = damage
        super().__init__(desc, name, usable, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\nDamage: {}".format(self.name, self.damage, self.desc, self.usable, self.value)


class BrokenSword(Weapon):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name="Broken Sword",
                                     desc="A sword that didn't resist time.",
                                     value=1,
                                     usable=0,
                                     damage=1)
```

PyCharm states that `desc, name, usable` and `value` in the `Weapon` class (inside `super().__init__()`) are unsolved references, and that they are unexpected arguments in the `BrokenSword(Weapon)` class. The code is very similar to the tutorial one, so what is wrong with it? Was the tutorial written in python 2.x? How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Weapon` class doesn't know what those arguments are. You have to define them either locally or -god forbid- globally. So `Weapon.__init__` should accept arguments:

```
class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, desc, name, usable, value, damage):
        super().__init__(
            desc=desc,
            name=name,
            usable=usable,
            value=value
        )
        self.damage = damage
```